# eth0 not being configured automatically

Tags: ubuntu, networking

When I start an ubuntu 12.10 instance, eth0 is NOT getting configured.

```
davidparks21@MySqlDB:~$ cat /run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
```

When I manually edit `ifstate` and add `eth0=eth0` and `service restart networking` then `eth0` gets configured properly and we're all happy.

Reboot though, and I loose the configuration and have to manually edit `ifstate` and add it again and restart networking.

What configuration might I be missing here?

---

```
root@prodweb1:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.1.3.10
 netmask 255.255.0.0
 broadcast 10.1.255.255
 gateway 10.1.0.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
 dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ip-addressing

Comment: Does `ifup -a` brings the interface up?

Comment: What's the output of `ip a s eth0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start your `eth0` at reboot you need to add an entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` like below for `eth0`.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have `auto eth0` `iface eth0 inet static` and all of the parameters configured. They take effect when I add eth0=eth0 to /run/network/ifstate correctly. But reboot and it doesn't configure eth0 properly.

Answer (score 0):

have you error messages related to eth0 at boot time? (look with `dmesg`)

maybe the driver for your ethernet card isn't loaded when the boot time configuration runs.

Comment: The only "error" I see in `dmesg` is `[20277.511852] type=1400 audit(1365069410.434:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 parent=18836 profile="lxc-container-default" name="/" pid=18847 comm="mount" flags="ro, remount"`, because this is an LXC container and mounts aren't allowed, but this doesn't seem related.

Comment: I also see this `[   13.985304] igb: em1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX`, perhaps it has something to do with me renaming `em1` on the host to `eth0` on the LXC container.

Comment: after googling a bit it seems the em# names are the new kernel naming for motherboard embedded ethernet cards. And there is a kernel boot option to disable that behaviour; so try adding `biosdevname=0` to the kernel booting options. alternatively, you could try configuring "em1" instead of "eth0" in /etc/network/interfaces file.